# passport: req.isAuthenticated() is not a function and req.user is not being set by passport

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, passport.js, express-session

I'm creating a web application using the MERN stack for which I want to implement google OAuth and session and I'm using 'express-session' and 'passport.js' for this. Everything seems to be working as expected but I'm getting an  `error: req.isAuthenticated isn't function`. Also,  `the value of req.user is "undefined"` but, the cookie is being generated and successfully stored in MongoDB. I'm new to node and passport so I'm not able to figure out the problem. Also, solutions to previously asked questions on this same error aren't working for me.

**This is the error**

```
(node:10481) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: req.isAuthenticated is not a function
    at addYear (/media/test/DATA/Dev/full-stack/projects/budget-app-backend/controllers/years.js:15:18)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/media/test/DATA/Dev/full-stack/projects/budget-app-backend/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/media/test/DATA/Dev/full-stack/projects/budget-app-backend/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/media/test/DATA/Dev/full-stack/projects/budget-app-backend/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/media/test/DATA/Dev/full-stack/projects/budget-app-backend/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at /media/test/DATA/Dev/full-stack/projects/budget-app-backend/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (/media/test/DATA/Dev/full-stack/projects/budget-app-backend/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:341:12)
    at next (/media/test/DATA/Dev/full-stack/projects/budget-app-backend/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
    at Function.handle (/media/test/DATA/Dev/full-stack/projects/budget-app-backend/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:174:3)
    at router (/media/test/DATA/Dev/full-stack/projects/budget-app-backend/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:47:12)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:10481) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:10481) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

I'm also adding the code for reference.

**code in server.js**

```
const dotenv = require("dotenv");
dotenv.config();
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const passport = require("passport");
const session = require("express-session");
const MongoStore = require("connect-mongo");
const authRouter = require("./routes/auth");
const Info = require("./models/Info");
const Transaction = require("./models/Transactions");
const recordsRouter = require("./routes/recordsRouter");
const { User, userSchema } = require("./models/Users");
const GoogleStrategy = require("passport-google-oauth20").Strategy;
const startDB = require("./models/db");

const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8000;

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(
    cors({
        origin: "http://localhost:3000",
        methods: "GET,POST,PUT,DELETE",
        credentials: true,
    })
);
app.use(
    session({
        secret: "some random string",
        resave: false,
        saveUninitialized: false,
        store: MongoStore.create({
            mongoUrl: "mongodb://0.0.0.0:37017/budgetDB",
        }),
    })
);

startDB();

app.use("/auth", authRouter);
app.use("/dashboard", recordsRouter);

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

require("./passport")(passport);

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server started listening on port ${PORT}.....`);
});
```

**code in passport.js**

```
const { User } = require("./models/Users");
const GoogleStrategy = require("passport-google-oauth20").Strategy;

module.exports = function (passport) {
    passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
        console.log(`From passport.js serializeUser: ${user}`);
        return done(null, user.id);
    });

    passport.deserializeUser((id, done) => {
        User.findById(id, (err, user) => {
            done(err, user);
        });
    });

    passport.use(
        new GoogleStrategy(
            {
                clientID: process.env.CLIENT_ID,
                clientSecret: process.env.CLIENT_SECRET,
                callbackURL: "http://localhost:8000/auth/google/callback",
                userProfileURL: "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo",
            },

            async (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
                const newUser = new User({
                    name: profile.displayName,
                    googleId: profile.id,
                });

                try {
                    const user = await User.findOne({ googleId: profile.id });
                    if (!user) {
                        user = await User.create(newUser);
                    }
                    return done(null, user);
                } catch (err) {
                    console.log(`Error From 'passport.js': ${err}`);
                    return done(err);
                }
            }
        )
    );
};
```

**code in auth.js**

```
const router = require("express").Router();
const passport = require("passport");

const CLIENT_URL = "http://localhost:3000";

router.get("/login/failed", (req, res) => {
    console.log(res);
    res.status(401).json({
        message: "login failed",
    });
});

router.get("/logout", (req, res) => {
    req.logout();
    res.redirect(CLIENT_URL);
});

router.get("/google", passport.authenticate("google", { scope: ["profile"] }));

router.get(
    "/google/callback",
    passport.authenticate("google", {
        failureRedirect: "/login/failed",
        successRedirect: CLIENT_URL + "/Dashboard",
    })
);

module.exports = router;
```

**code in User model**

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    googleId: String,
});

const User = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);

module.exports = { User, userSchema };
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Middlewares orders is important. Put the `.use(passport...)` before the `.use(router...)`